# Django QuerySets and cache

Tags: django, caching, optimization, query-optimization

I have a method in some of my Object Managers, that fetches data from db:

```
def products(self, offset=None)
```

if there is no `offset` passed, it simply returns *all* objects (approximately 5000, not so much). If there is `offest` it returns, well, objects with offset.

This method used a lot during application life-cycle. I guess it's reasonable to somehow cache its results.

My question is: will `functools.lru_cache` do the job or should I consider using Django's caches? Or maybe I should just not to think about it prematurely?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends where you are trying to optimize. [Django caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/) (not to be confused with [QuerySet caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets) which is an important aspect of their behavior to be conscious of) is used when you want to skip the dynamic part of serving up a dynamic page. So the main thought when using those is will (and for how long) the content I present to the user not change? In terms of optimizing your call into products, [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) will give you a simple in-memory cache but your main concern will be how often to bust the cache with cache_clear(). To fully answer your question:

Caching *typically* won't hurt but it may also not be necessary if you aren't noticing performance issues. If you are worried about not hammering the database so much when using products(), you can leverage lru_cache and you'll need to decide when/if to cache bust which is informed by the nature of your data. That being said, databases are highly optimized for retrievals like this, and it may not be worth the extra logic depending on your application. Plus, you'll want to consider how much stuff that was in persistent store you are now keeping in-memory and if that trade-off is worth it.

If you are constantly regenerating the same pages to present to users, look into using Django caching. Skipping the steps prior to products() as well can only help if they are indeed stable for some period of time.

Personally, I would just leave lru_cache alone (and any idea of adding extra caching directly to your db query) based on what you have described. This sort of in-memory caching can be helpful for things that are accessed often and have to be computed a single time, calls that are very expensive yet yield the same result(s), situations where you have to call external APIs that have fees/are unreliable, etc. I would cache toward the presentation layer if it seems like you are constantly presenting the same page(s) to users before heaping complexity in front of the ORM - you probably want your managers to actually interact with your models as expected when called.

### Followup 12-10-16

Since this answer I have had the opportunity to use [django cachalot](http://django-cachalot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and have found it works very well if you decide you do want to cache database queries. It requires little effort to setup and has a wonderful exploration of the trade-offs in the documentation.

### Followup 08-05-20

`django_cachalot` is not compatible with latest Django currently (3.1+) so I would not still recommend it nor do I currently use it. If you need heavier ORM caching, [django_cacheops](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops) is current and viable.

Comment: I'd like to note that the project upon which I'm currently working had cachalot on it when I started, and there were also numerous incredibly hard to reproduce bugs to do with database queries.  We went as far as moving database provider from self-hosting to managed, solving nothing.  When I learnt what cachalot was doing, I removed it immediately, and not only did that class of bug disappear, the majority of our (poorly written) views actually sped up.

Comment: Since this followup, I've actually not used `cachalot` again since it is not compatible with newer versions of Django. I have used `django-cacheops`, which requires a more concerted approach and configuration, and has its own quirks (particularly in the admin). It does less "magic" than cachalot. I don't imagine I could/would use `cachalot` again as all projects I work on try to stay on the latest stable and secure Django. Thanks for your note, I'll amend the answer since it has been quite some time.